# Having problems scanning a String from a file in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan a line of text from a .txt file, split it up into seven numbers, change two of the numbers, and then write the new numbers back into the .txt file. The code below works fine the first time, but seems to have issues with reading from the text file a second time for the new starting String. I've done very similar things multiple times and had no issues, so I'm really not sure why I'm having problems this time around. The code I currently have is:

```
public void addWin(int numGuesses) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(*filepath*);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(*filepath*));
    String temp = "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";
    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        temp = scan.nextLine();
    }
    String[] statsArr = temp.split(";");
    scan.close();
    statsArr[0] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(statsArr[0]) + 1);
    statsArr[numGuesses] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(statsArr[numGuesses]) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < statsArr.length; i++) {
        writer.append(statsArr[i] + ";");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Some extra context if needed, this is essentially for a Wordle clone sort of thing for a Discord bot I have. *numGuesses* is the number of guesses it took to get the word correct. The String being written in and being read is 7 numbers divided up by a semicolon, the first number is the current win streak, the second number is number of times you've won in 1 guess, and so on. The testing I've done seems to place the error somewhere before the scanner closes. A first run through will correctly write the numbers, so if the word was guessed in 3 attempts the file will contain "1;0;0;1;0;0;0;", but the next time the method is called it essentially starts from scratch. Checking the *temp* variable just after the if statement on a second run through just shows "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;". Sorry for the long-windedness, just trying to provide all possibly helpful details. Thank you in advance!

-

Comment: what is the contents of the file you are trying to read?

Comment: You said "The code below works fine the first time, but seems to have issues with reading from the text file a second time for the new starting String". What kind of issues is it having, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @hfontanez The contents should be whatever was written into the file during the previous time the code ran. So if the code had previously written "1;1;0;0;0;0;0;" into the file, it should grab that same String back from the file. However, it seems to always just continue with the default String of "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;".

Comment: What does [tag:class] have to do with it? Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Consider what happens on this line if the file is blank for some reason `if (scan.hasNextLine())`, you will get the default temp value of `String temp = "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";`. Change that to be `String temp = "";` so that you know if the file is broken, of not.

Comment: You need to create the `Scanner` first, do the reading, close it, then create the `FileWriter`, do the writing, and close that. At present you are always reading from a new empty file.

Comment: @sorifiend you were getting my point....

Comment: @EmrahDiril The issue is that it just doesn't seem to grab the text from the file at all. The goal is to have the code write a String into the file (which is does successfully), then the next time it runs take that same String and increment certain parts of it by 1. The if statement at the start is meant to check if the file has a String, and if it does use that as the base. However, every time the class is ran it ends up using the default String of "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;" to start with rather than the String previously contained within the file.

Comment: @ih8mondays1 if I am not mistaken, if the file denoted in the _filepath_ doesn't exist, `FileWriter` will create a blank file. Then, you open a `Scanner` to the same (potentially empty) file. So, when you get to the... I just saw what user207421 wrote. My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) which states "*Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform.*". So what is happening here, is that when you use `new FileWriter(*filepath*)` the file is being locked/created blank, so when you use `new Scanner(new File(*filepath*));` and `scan.hasNextLine()` you get a null/empty value.

The easy solution is to simply move the FileWriter further down in your code, and only open it after the scanner has been closed. Also add an `else` to your `if` statement so you know if there is an issue with reading from the scanner:

```
//Move the below line to be later in the code
//FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(*filepath*);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(*filepath*));
String temp = "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";
if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    temp = scan.nextLine();
}
//Add some debugging
else{
    System.out.println("ERROR no data could be read");
}
String[] statsArr = temp.split(";");
scan.close();
statsArr[0] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(statsArr[0]) + 1);
statsArr[numGuesses] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(statsArr[numGuesses]) + 1);

//Create the flie writer here instead
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(*filepath*);
for (int i = 0; i < statsArr.length; i++) {
    writer.append(statsArr[i] + ";");
}
writer.close();
```

Now assuming the file exists and can be edited, and where `numGuesses = 3`, then for the following contents:

> 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;

The output of running the code is as expected (+1 to the 0 and 3rd index)

> 2;2;3;5;5;6;7;

The reason you only saw `0;0;0;0;0;0;0;` was because the code was failing to read from the scanner, and always using the temp value from this line `String temp = "0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";`. By adding the `else` check above we can see when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(*filepath*);` clears the contents of the file you are trying to read from. You need to move this line after `scan.close();`